# Distributed AG on SQL Server 2017 Standard Edition?

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, sql-server-2017, standard-edition, distributed-availability-groups

Can I configure Distributed AG with SQL Server 2017 Standard Edition?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can't. That is one of the basic availability groups limitations.

[Limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/basic-availability-groups-always-on-availability-groups?view=sql-server-ver15#limitations)

> Basic availability groups can not be part of a distributed
>   availability group.